# How to import service class in seed process in nestjs and prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

In my service class has special function to parse text to data that want to insert into database. This is the code but get `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error.

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
const service = new UserQuestionService();

export const QuestionSeed = async () => {
  // read txt and do some process here
};
```